# I can't get this React action's return statement to run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

The following code is a React action that is supposed to dispatch to a reducer. I can't seem to get the return statement to run. I can get it to hit a debugger right blelow the data variable declaration, but that's it. If I try to run the rest of the code within debugger, I'm getting a reference error "Return is not a function". I can't figure out what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001'
export const signUp = (user) => {
let data = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ user })
}

   return dispatch => {
  fetch(`${ baseUrl }/signup`, data)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(user => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('user', user)

      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_USER',
        payload: user.current
      })


    })
    .catch(err => err)
}
```

}

Comment: What you are returning is an entire function that in turns needs to be dispatched in order to actually trigger the corresponding reducer action. You'll need a middleware like redux-thunk to handle that kind of action footprint.

Comment: Thanks, Jaxx. I actually am using Thunk, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: That's because you return an arrow function from your `signUp` method. Please update formatting in your code snippet.

Comment: That's odd, I don't see anything wrong with your action, then. How do you call it in your application?

Comment: It's a controlled form using connect.

Comment: grumbler-chester. Can you explainw why it would be a problem to return an arrow function? Thanks.

Comment: @mossexploding if you place console logs within the then statements (like `console.log(response)` and `console.log(data)`), do you see any activity? Also, in your devtools network tab, can you see the fetch call taking place?

Comment: Meant `console.log(user)` not `data`, sorry.

Comment: Jaxx - no the return statement doesn't run at all. If I put a debugger right below the data varialbe declaration, I can run the fetch and hit my api thought. It just won't run the return statment.

Comment: Here's the object logged with (user)

Comment: Object { username: "test", password: "test" }

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using `redux-thunk` you are missing the parameters inside for your function and currently you have just `user`. Try this:

`export const signUp = (dispatch, getState, user) => {
...your code
}`

Comment: I've used thunk before without ever having to pass in these arguments, so no.

Comment: Yea - I don't think that's the issue either. I'm using connect and mapDispatchToProps to pass the signUp action to a submit function in my component.

Comment: within your function signUp, can you console(dispatch) and print the results here?

Comment: Kleo - I think your'e onto something here. I'm still pretty new to redux, so I'm not sure. If I put a debugger right below the data variable - dispatch returns ReferenceError not defined. Maybe I have something wired up wrong? It seemed to be working in other components. Thanks.

Comment: would help if we could see your code at that relevant component